# Merge columns from two text character-seperated text files

Tags: php, explode

I have 2 files for example

`file1.txt` and  `file2.txt`, each containing rows of two columns, seperated by a `:` character.

`file1.txt` contains for example following content: (I want to use the first 'column')

```
a:b
markus:lanz
peter:heinrichs
lach:schnell
```

and `file2.txt` contains for example following content (I want to use the second 'column')

```
b:c
lanz:hallo
heinrichs:gruss
schnell:langsam
```

So I'm looking for the following output:

```
a:c
markus:hallo
peter:gruss
lach:langsam
```

How is this possible?

My current code is following:

```
<?php
    $file1 = 'a:b
    markus:lanz
    peter:heinrichs
    lach:schnell';

    $file2 = '
    lanz:hallo
    heinrichs:gruss
    b:c
    test:notest
    schnell:langsam';

    $array = explode(":", $file1);
    for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        $array = explode(":", $file1);
        $pattan = $array[$i];
        $pattern = '=\n'. $pattan .':(.*)\n=sUm';
        $result = preg_match($pattern, $file2, $subpattern);

        echo "<br>";
        echo $array[$i];
        $first = $array[$i];
        echo "<br>";
    }

    $pattern = '=\n'. $first .':(.*)\n=sUm';
    $result = preg_match($pattern, $file2, $subpattern);
    var_dump($subpattern);
?>
```

Comment: Start with writing some code. No one will do it for you.

Comment: SHow what you have tried, then we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using `preg_split` and `array_map` functions:

```
$file1_content = "a:b
markus:lanz
peter:heinrichs
lach:schnell";

$file2_content = "b:c
lanz:hallo
heinrichs:gruss
schnell:langsam";

// \R modifier matches line break among all platforms (\r\n|\n|\r)
$file1_parts = preg_split('/\R/', $file1_content);
$file2_parts = preg_split('/\R/', $file2_content);

$cross_result = array_map(function($fp1, $fp2){
    return explode(":", $fp1)[0] .":". explode(":", $fp2)[1] . PHP_EOL;
}, $file1_parts, $file2_parts);

$cross_result = implode("", $cross_result);

print_r($cross_result);
```

The output:

```
a:c
markus:hallo
peter:gruss
lach:langsam
```

Comment: thank you very much sir. and if i want to addiotnal to do that from a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i

Comment: welcome, could you explain what does mean "to do that from a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i" ?

Comment: <?php

$file1_content = "a:b
markus:lanz
peter:heinrichs
lach:schnell";

$file2_content = "lanz:hallo
b:c
heinrichs:gruss
schnell:langsam";

// \R modifier matches line break among all platforms (\r\n|\n|\r)
$file1_parts = preg_split('/\R/', $file1_content);
$file2_parts = preg_split('/\R/', $file2_content);

$cross_result = array_map(function($fp1, $fp2){
    return explode(":", $fp1)[0] .":". explode(":", $fp2)[1]. PHP_EOL;
}, $file1_parts, $file2_parts);

$cross_result = implode("", $cross_result);

print_r($cross_result);

?>

Comment: if i have a different order on file1 and file 2 what can i do then?

Comment: in your case, the order should be strict, otherwise you'll receive irrelevant pairs, like `a:hallo` or `peter:lansgram`

Comment: yes but how can i do that with the script that the script is searching after this?

Comment: you have to define the "relation" rule beforehand, which will coordinate the script search logic

Comment: Because random "relations" search will give random results

Answer (score 0):

```
$file1 = 'a:b
markus:lanz
peter:heinrichs
lach:schnell';
$array1 = explode("\n", $file1);

$file2 = 'b:c
lanz:hallo
heinrichs:gruss
schnell:langsam';
$array2 = explode("\n", $file2);

$array3 = array();

foreach($array1 as $i => $value) {
    $key = explode(':',$value)[0];
    $val = explode(':',$array2[$i])[1];
    $array3[] = $key.':'.$val;
}

$file3 = implode("\n",$array3);
```

Comment: if i have a different order on $file1 and $file2 f.e. like: 
$file1 = 'markus:lanz
a:b
peter:heinrichs
lach:schnell';
$array1 = explode("\n", $file1);

$file2 = 'b:c
lanz:hallo
heinrichs:gruss
schnell:langsam';
$array2 = explode("\n", $file2);

Answer (score 0):

my thought / my code is like that

not working

but before some people hates or something like that:

```
<?php
$file1 = 'a:b
markus:lanz
peter:heinrichs
lach:schnell';

$file2 = '
lanz:hallo
heinrichs:gruss
b:c
test:notest
schnell:langsam';





  $array = explode(":", $file1);


  for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) {



$pattern = "/^.*\b". $array[$i] ."\b.*$/m";
$matches = array();
preg_match($pattern, $file2, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

   echo $array[$i] . ":";
  }

?>
```